# Determine if UTF-8 text is all ASCII?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii

What's the fastest way, in PHP, to determine if some given UTF-8 text is purely ASCII or not?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A possibly faster function would be to use a negative character class (since the regex can just stop when it hits the first character, and there's no need to internally capture anything):

```
function isAscii($str) {
    return 0 == preg_match('/[^\x00-\x7F]/', $str);
}
```

Without regex (based on my comment) {

```
function isAscii($str) {
    $len = strlen($str) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        if (ord($str[$i]) > 127) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But I'd have to ask, why are you so concerned about faster?  Use the more readable and easier to understand version, and only worry about optimizing it when you *know* it's a problem...

**Edit**:

Another option is [`mb_check_encoding`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-check-encoding.php):

```
function isAscii($str) {
    return mb_check_encoding($str, 'ASCII');
}
```

Comment: this will be run over a lot of text frequently, and I think both of those are pretty readable, so faster is definitely better here.

Comment: @philfreo: Updated an answer...  But the best way for you to tell what's fastest is to actually benchmark the options using your conditions...

Comment: but apparently php's ord function has issues with utf-8

Comment: No, `ord()` is always a single-byte "value of this byte" function.

Comment: Note that `mb_check_encoding` is extremely slow, the `preg_match` approach will win, always.

Comment: __BENCHMARK__ (on small ASCII string): reg exp is the fastest approach. for loop and `mb_check_encoding` are ~7x slower.

Answer (score 2):

Check if any byte is greater than 0x7f, or any character is above U+007F.

Comment: Quite simple `$isNotAscii = false; for ($i=0,$len=strlen($string);$i<$len;$i++) { if (ord($string[$i]) > 127) { $isNotAscii = true; break; } }`.  It iterates over each character of the string looking for a character > 127...

Comment: I believe preg_match will be faster in this case... did not benchmark but for strings pattern matching, it almost always is

Answer (score 1):

```
function isAscii($str) {
    return preg_match('/^([\x00-\x7F])*$/', $str);
}

// doesn't accept ASCII control characters
function isAsciiText($str) {
    return preg_match('/^([\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\x7E])*$/', $str);
}
```

Comment: this will fail on some valid ASCII control characters