# How do I detect non-ASCII characters in a string?

Tags: php, string

If I have a PHP string, how can I determine if it contains at least one non-ASCII character or not, in an efficient way? And by non-ASCII character, I mean any character that is not part of this table, http://www.asciitable.com/, positions 32 - 126 inclusive.

So not only does it have to be part of the ASCII table, but it also has to be printable. I want to detect a string that contains at least one character that does not meet these specifications (either non-printable ASCII, or a different character altogether, such as a Unicode character that is not part of that table.

Comment: So you do not mean Unicode, but non `US-ASCII`? I think this is worth to specify if you're looking for something efficient.

Comment: Can you make any safe assumption about the string, such as encoding?

Comment: All ASCII characters are <= 127, and any UTF-8 character sequence that decodes to a non-ASCII character has at least one byte with the highest bit set. Thus, if you have no byte >127, it's ASCII. Detecting UTF-8 encoding as suggested in the answers below will probably work too, but could possibly be ambiguous (since ASCII characters are incidentially _also_ UTF-8 characters).

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147646/determine-if-utf-8-text-is-all-ascii

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I found it more useful to detect if any character falls out of the list

```
if(preg_match('/[^\x20-\x7e]/', $string))
```

Comment: This answer is good but you can find more solutions in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147646/determine-if-utf-8-text-is-all-ascii

Comment: @wheresrhys I think your snippets tests if all characters in string are ascii, for any character code should be `/[^\x20-\x7f]/.test(theString)`

Answer (score 44):

You can use [`mb_detect_encoding`](http://php.net/mb_detect_encoding) and check for ASCII:

```
mb_detect_encoding($str, 'ASCII', true)
```

This will return *false* if `$str` contains at least one non-ASCI character (byte value > 0x7F).

Comment: [`mb_check_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-check-encoding.php) would be more appropriate: `mb_check_encoding($str, 'ASCII')`

Answer (score 4):

Try ([mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php)). For example:

```
mb_check_encoding($identifier, 'ASCII');
```

Answer (score 4):

The function [ctype_print](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-print.php) returns true iff all characters fall into the ASCII range 32-126 ([PHP unit test](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/ctype/tests/ctype_print_variation2.phpt)).

Comment: `php -r 'echo ctype_print("\xa0");'` prints `1` so there's something fishy with this function.

Comment: @forthrin: I cannot confirm that. For me, `php -r 'var_dump(ctype_print("\xa0"));'` returns false (using PHP 7.0.10).

Comment: I'm on PHP 7.0.10 too, Homebrew version (OS X). Could the difference be caused by terminal, locale, php.ini or other environmental factors?

Comment: Doesn't work for me either, PHP 7.0.5 on Windows - no idea why. It does not seem to work anymore. We should probably open a bug report?

Answer (score 4):

I benchmarked the suggested functions as I need this check for batch processing of shorter (1000 characters max) strings. I tested 10k iterations of 30 different strings (empty, short, longer, ascii, accents, japanese, emoji, non-ascii start, non-ascii end etc). Here are the rough results:

**mb_check_encoding**: 95ms average. Performance degrades way faster than preg_match and ctype as the strings get longer (1MB+).

```
mb_check_encoding($input, 'ASCII');
```

**preg_match**: 85ms average. Decently fast for 1MB+ strings (walks the string, so faster if there are non-ascii characters early in the string).

```
!preg_match('/[\\x80-\\xff]/', $input);
```

**ctype_print**: 83ms average. Decently fast for 1MB+ strings (walks the string, so faster if there are non-ascii characters early in the string). **DO NOTE that this is not really an ascii check**.

```
ctype_print($input);
```

**while/ord**: 500ms average. I'm still waiting for the 1MB+ strings test to finish.

```
function is_ascii($input) {
    $num = 0;
    while( isset( $string[$num] ) ) {
        if( ord( $string[$num] ) & 0x80 ) {
            return false;
        }
        $num++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try: ([Source](http://pageconfig.com/post/how-to-validate-ascii-text-in-php))

```
function is_ascii( $string = '' ) {
    return ( bool ) ! preg_match( '/[\\x80-\\xff]+/' , $string );
}
```

Although, all of the above answers are correct, but depending upon the input, these solutions may give wrong answers. See the last section in [this ASCII validation post](http://pageconfig.com/post/how-to-validate-ascii-text-in-php).

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

[mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mb-detect-encoding.php)

but it will be maybe not as precise as you want it to be.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you look into utf8_encode or utf8_decode under PHP's manual:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Look into the examples down below as it may have something there that leads you to the right direction if not finding what you are looking for.