# How to transform a string to lowercase with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, unicode, preg-replace

I just stuck at this and cannot find solution. 
I would like to try to transform a string to lower case using `preg_replace`.
I just cannot create the right regex.
The reason is that normal `strtolower` does not support unicode characters.
I know that I could use `mb_strtolower` but this function seems to be quite slow and beside them not everyone has MB support.

Any clue?

Regards,
Radek

EDIT: Ok, thanks alot for your help guys. I think my approach was not quite correct.
I think it would be much better to use this: [How do I detect non-ASCII characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497685/how-do-i-detect-non-ascii-characters-in-a-string) and then respectively use either the strtolower or mb_strtolower if available.

Comment: I'm curios, what makes you think that regex would actually be faster than mb_strtolower?

Comment: you can use strtolower() php function to convert sting into lower case.

Comment: @andreas I'm not sure. Basically wanted to test it first.

Comment: @RukmiPatel But you didn't read what I wrote. Did you? ;)

Comment: @andreas I did some test. `preg_replace` seems 40-50 times faster than `mb_strtolower`. But ofc i didnt put all the rules

Comment: I'd think that `strtolower` works if you set the correct locale... or am I wrong? Have you tried it with the correct locale?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regex is not able to change characters by itself, it can only change their order and/or add additional characters/delete some of them.

There is [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) or [/e](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) flag, but they can manipulate only with known functions, and therefore can't do better than strtolower.

If you can't rely on existense of mb_strolower function, you will have to implement it yourself.

Comment: SO it's basically not possible?

Comment: Yes, it is basically not possible. Regex is a tool for pattern matching and string recomposition, it can't transform chars on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a preg_replace for this because preg_replace is used to match a certain pattern and replace it with something else. Wat you want is to replace every single uppercase character with a lowercase one, so no need to match a pattern.

mb_strtolower would be the way to go, and if you don't have the mb_ functions you'll have to write a function yourself using a lot of str_replace's...

Comment: Yes but mb_stratolower is so damn slow. I did some test with to compare mb_strlower and native strtolower and MB seems to be about 30 times slower than the native one.

My biggest problem is that at the time I have to do the strtolower I don't know if I have unicode characters within the string or not.

Comment: Maybe first use strtolower, then use preg_replace_callback to replace all characters that are not default lowercase characters (/[^a-z]+/)  and then use mb_strtolower for that

Comment: I came here because I was looking for a way to "decaptialize" a string (e.g. turn "`The War of NextGen`" to "`the war of nextGen`"  -  so for this case lower-casing the entire string will NOT work for me. I was trying to use preg_replace with `"/\b(\w)/"` and the replace string as `strtolower("$1")` - but it doesn't work! Surely there should be a way?