# Replace an upper-case string with lower-case using preg_replace() and regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Is it possible to replace an upper-case with lower-case using `preg_replace` and `regex`?

For example:

The following string:

```
$x="HELLO LADIES!";
```

I want to convert it to:

```
 hello ladies!
```

using `preg_replace()`:

```
 echo preg_replace("/([A-Z]+)/","$1",$x);
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that with `preg_replace` alone as there is no pattern. Why not using `strtolower` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to transform a string to lowercase with preg\_replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939066/how-to-transform-a-string-to-lowercase-with-preg-replace)

Comment: Is `strtolower()` to simple a solution?

Comment: `$x="HELLO LADIES!"; $x=strtolower($x);` ;-) as a quick one-liner if you don't need the preg_ function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert array values to lowercase in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008443/how-to-convert-array-values-to-lowercase-in-php)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to accomplish:

```
$x="HELLO LADIES! This is a test";
echo preg_replace_callback('/\b([A-Z]+)\b/', function ($word) {
      return strtolower($word[1]);
      }, $x);
```

Output:

```
hello ladies! This is a test
```

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/tD7sI0/1

If you just want the whole string to be lowercase though than just use `strtolower` on the whole thing.

Comment: I did not know it would be so easy with strtolower() and preg_replace() together. Thanks chris.

Comment: Fantastic solution. I've just spent ages trying to look up / find out how to capitalise a capture group in PHP's PCRE Regex. It never occurred to me that PHP might have its own native function for transforming capture groups using PHP, rather than regex syntax.