# Extract any unicode string occurence within a string using preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have this kind of string

```
sample İletişim form:: aşağıdaki formu
```

What I'm aiming is to extract the string that has a unicode/non-ascii character inside of it using preg_match or preg_match_all of php.

So I'm expecting a result of 2 **İletişim** and **aşağıdaki** word only.

```
Array
(
    [0] => İletişim 
    [1] => aşağıdaki
)
```

I just can't think of regular expression as I'm not good at it.
Any aid is welcome.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a beginning of solution you want is here: [How do I detect non-ASCII characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497685/how-do-i-detect-non-ascii-characters-in-a-string)

By using preg_match(), you could do smthg like this:

```
preg_match_all('/[^\s]*[^\x20-\x7f]+[^\s]*/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Or, without preg_match, you can use the function mb_detect_encoding() to test the encoding of the string. In your case, you could use it this way:

```
$matches = array_filter(explode(' ', $string), function($item) {
    return !mb_detect_encoding($item, 'ASCII', TRUE);
});
print_r($matches);
```

But the last one is a bit warped ^^

Comment: I tested the code and it return only the non-ascii characters not the whole string that contain that character. maybe yes it might be a step to achieve what I want. Thank you anyway

Comment: I found one that works well. Try it with preg_match_all(): `'/[^\s]*[^\x20-\x7f]+[^\s]*/'`;

Answer (score 1):

You can use unicode properties:

```
$string = 'sample İletişim form:: aşağıdaki formu';
preg_match_all("/(\pL+)/u", $string, $matches); 
print_r($matches);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => sample
            [1] => İletişim
            [2] => form
            [3] => aşağıdaki
            [4] => formu
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => sample
            [1] => İletişim
            [2] => form
            [3] => aşağıdaki
            [4] => formu
        )

)
```

Comment: This one extract the other strings that doesn't have a non-ascii on it. But thanks for contributing. Appreciate it :)