# Check if url contain a specific non-Latin word (eg Greek) using php

Tags: php

I use the code below to check if the URL contains a specific word (eg. foobar):

```
<?php $geturl = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>

<?php if (strpos($geturl, 'foobar') == true) {   
//Do something here
} ?>
```

This works pretty much perfect but if i try to search for a Greek word (eg. καλημέρα)

```
<?php if (strpos($geturl, 'καλημέρα') == true) {   
//Do something here
} ?>
```

then it doesn't work. I tried to use also `mb_strpos` and didn't work too. How can i make it work ?

UPDATE: If i try to echo the saved url with `<?php echo $geturl; ?>` i am getting this:

```
/myserver/%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B7%CE%BC%CE%AD%CF%81%CE%B1
```

Instead it should be like that:

```
/myserver/καλημέρα
```

Comment: Can you provide string example with greek part, I mean `$geturl` with greek in it, because there is no errors in your code?

Comment: I have no idea where this "%CE.." comes from. With urldecode("/myserver/%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B7%CE%BC%CE%AD%CF%81%CE%B1") you get "/myserver/καλημέρα"

Comment: You need to use `urldecode($geturl)` to convert the urlencoded URL to its corresponding characters and then you should use `mb_strpos`. Remeber, greek characters themselves are not valid in a URL that's why they are URL encoded when you receive them

Comment: thanks @apokryfos i will try your suggestion.

Comment: mb_strpos () only needs to be used if the position of the character is to be determined. To check whether the string is contained strpos() is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

For this case a`preg_match` can do the job for you. You need to match anything that is not in a default character set. In this case I assume that the greek characters are not inside ASCII.

According to [this answer by Karolis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6497946), you could try to use the following:

```
if(preg_match('/[^\x20-\x7e]/', $string))
```

Answer (score -1):

That is not correct

```
if (strpos($geturl, 'foobar') == true) ..
```

You must use

```
if( strpos($geturl, 'καλημέρα') !== false){
  //do
}
```

If the word you are looking for is somewhere in the string, [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) returns a numeric value. It returns false if nothing is found. It never returns true.

**Update:**
Use for $geturl that

```
$geturl = 'http://' . urldecode($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Comment: `== true` will pass for any number greater than 0 so technically in this case it would work (it would only not work if the needle is found at the beginning of the haystack)

Comment: Even if it works for the special case here, this remains unclean.