# PHP JSON Data Retrieval Query - [Solved]

Tags: php, arrays, json

I wonder if someone could avise where I am going wrong.

Using PHP the following code is being used successfully to fetched the JSON array from an external source:

```
$jsonData   = file_get_contents($link);
```

... following which the retrieved data appears to have also been successfully re-built and converted into a PHP array using the following code:

```
array_push($AllTable1, array(

    "bookingid"  => $bookingid2,
    "dayname"    => $dayname6,
    "daydate"    => $daydate4,
    "monthname"  => $monthname,
    "starttime"  => $starttime4,
    "title"      => $title7,
    "room"       => $room7,
    "roomcol"    => $roomcol,
    "roomcol2"   => $roomcol2

));
```

When the following code is run:

```
$AllTable1 = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $AllTable1);
echo json_encode($AllTable1, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

... data in the following format is successfully returned without any associated errors:

```
0   
    bookingid   "window.open('https://<pathtobooking>')"
    dayname "Mon"
    daydate "04"
    monthname   "December"
    starttime   "10:30"
    title   "Yoga Classes"
    room    "Large Hall"
    roomcol "#b30c35"
    roomcol2    ""
1   
    bookingid   "window.open('https://<pathtobooking>')"
    dayname "Mon"
    daydate "04"
    monthname   "December"
    starttime   "19:00"
    title   "History Group"
    room    "Small Hall"
    roomcol "#428bca"
    roomcol2    ""
2   
    bookingid   "window.open('https://<pathtobooking>')"
    dayname "Tue"
    daydate "05"
    monthname   "December"
    starttime   "10:00"
    title   "All Welcome Coffee Morning"
    room    "Kitchen,Small Hall"
    roomcol "#41753f"
    roomcol2    "#428bca"
3   
    bookingid   "window.open('https://<pathtobooking>')"
    dayname "Tue"
    daydate "05"
    monthname   "December"
    starttime   "20:30"
    title   "Table Tennis Club"
    room    "Large Hall"
    roomcol "#b30c35"
    roomcol2    ""
4   
    ... etc,etc
```

However, when the following code is run:

```
print_r($AllTable1);
```

... the following error is returned along with the array data:

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [bookingid] => window.open('https://<pathtobooking>')
            [dayname] => Mon
            [daydate] => 04
            [monthname] => December
            [starttime] => 10:30
            [title] => Yoga Classes
            [room] => Large Hall
            [roomcol] => #b30c35
            [roomcol2] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [bookingid] => window.open('https://<pathtobooking>')
            [dayname] => Mon
            [daydate] => 04
            [monthname] => December
            [starttime] => 19:00
            [title] => History Group
            [room] => Small Hall
            [roomcol] => #428bca
            [roomcol2] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [bookingid] => window.open('https://<pathtobooking>')
            [dayname] => Tue
            [daydate] => 05
            [monthname] => December
            [starttime] => 10:00
            [title] => All Welcome Coffee Morning
            [room] => Kitchen,Small Hall
            [roomcol] => #41753f
            [roomcol2] => #428bca
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [bookingid] => window.open('https://<pathtobooking>')
            [dayname] => Tue
            [daydate] => 05
            [monthname] => December
            [starttime] => 20:30
            [title] => Table Tennis Club
            [room] => Large Hall
            [roomcol] => #b30c35
            [roomcol2] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        ... etc,etc
```

Also, wheneer the following code is run to attempt to output data from the array, for example:

```
$ddata = json_encode($AllTable1, true);
echo("The day of the sixth booking in the list is: \n");
echo $ddata[5]['dayname'];
```

... the following error and output is returned (There are more than six sets of data in the array, btw.):

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

The day of the sixth booking in the list is:
```

Effectively, the error remains and no data is returned.

Is it possibly that the data is not correctly formatted? If so, I cannot see why as the array data appears to be returned correctly in both the above array examples provided, despite the JSON error.

I'd be very grateful if anyone could assist and advise what is being done wrong and what needs to be done to resolve the issue.

Comment: [How do I detect non-ASCII characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6497685/2943403) let us know exactly what odd characters you find as part of your [mcve].  There is very little chance that this is a unique question.

Comment: you should use json_decode($json_string,true); to convert json string to array 
so the $json_string=json_encode($AllTable1, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

Comment: When you are passing JSON from PHP to JavaScript, you can *only* pass the JSON, not any other characters, otherwise the JSON is invalid. So your `print_r($AllTable1);` and `echo("The day of the sixth booking in the list is: \n");
echo $ddata[5]['dayname'];` are outputting text into the response that are not JSON, and `JSON.parse` is failing because of them. The *only* thing your PHP should be sending is the output of `json_encode`.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, mickmackusa, AMA and Nick,

Comment: Thank you again for your replies, mickmackusa, AMA and Nick. 
I changed the following code: 
$ddata = json_encode($AllTable1, true);
echo("The day of the sixth booking in the list is: \n");
echo $ddata[5]['dayname'];
to:
$ddata = json_decode($AllTable1, true);
mb_check_encoding($ddata, 'ASCII');
... ran it and no FALSE was returned. So all the data appears to be valid ASCii text.

Comment: In the end the issue with the errors being reurned and non-display of data was found to be the inclusion of the following line of code at the beginning of the file:
header('Content-Type: application/json');
Commenting out/removing that line got rid of all the error messages. Then replacing:
$AllTable1 = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $AllTable1);
echo json_encode($AllTable1, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
... with:
$AllTable1 = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $AllTable1);
echo json_encode($AllTable1, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
$output = json_decode($AllTable1, true);
print_r($output);
... returned all the data.